# Fiber run function return undefined

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have code like this

```
var res = Fiber(function() {
  var report;
  // some asynchronous operations, result is in report
  return report;
}).run();
```

and in res, I have undefined everytime. Instead of return, I tried Fiber.yield(report) but it isn't helped. What to do with this? I'm using Meteor by the way.

Function inside fiber works well, console.log returns good result.

Comment: works perfectly fine for me; are you your bug is not in the code you don't show?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I realized why it's not working. Meteor server code runs in fiber, so, theres no need for another fiber. Another stacked fiber caused that strange error.